# Outlook Addin is working fine in windows 2007 and office 2016, but plugin is not getting Loaded in windows 2010 and office 2016

Tags: outlook-addin

I have created Outlook add-in in c# visual studio 2013 ,which is working fine in windows 2007 and office 2016, but plugin is not getting Loaded in windows 2010 and office 2016.

1.add-in is not available under disabled COM add-in list.
2.Its registry value of load behaviour is 3 i.e loaded.

Comment: What are trying to tell in the Number list? is it the sequence of events?

Comment: These are the things I have confirmed in outlook and registry values respectively.

Comment: Check the bitness of Office 2016 that runs on Windows 10.